# EJuiDateTimePicker Yii Set second datetimepicker minimum time depend on first datetimepicker selection

Tags: php, yii, datetimepicker, yii-extensions

i am using EJuiDateTimePicker. there is two  EJuiDateTimePicker. one for start time and another is end time. Now i can set `minDate` of  second datetimepicker on select of first datetimepicker.

But What i want is i cant set minimum time for second datetimepicker. How to set minimum time in time slider on select of first datetimepicker. i dont want to allow user to select  minimum time less then first datetimepicker

First Datetimepicker

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.EJuiDateTimePicker.EJuiDateTimePicker', array(
                        'model' => $model, //Model object
                        'attribute' => 'StartTime', //attribute name
                        'language' => 'en',
                        'mode' => 'datetime', //use "time","date" or "datetime" (default)
                        'options' => array(
                            'dateFormat' => 'dd-mm-yy',
                            'timeFormat' => 'HH:mm:ss',
                        'onSelect' => 'js:function( selectedDate ) {     $("#JobSchedule_EndTime").datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }'), // jquery plugin options
                            'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'form-control floating-label','readonly'=>true,'placeholder'=>'Start Date','value'=>$startTime),
                        ));
```

Second Datetimepicker

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.EJuiDateTimePicker.EJuiDateTimePicker', array(
                        'model' => $model, //Model object
                        'attribute' => 'EndTime', //attribute name
                        'language' => 'en',
                        'mode' => 'datetime', //use "time","date" or "datetime" (default)
                        'options' => array('dateFormat' => 'dd-mm-yy','minDate'=>($model->isNewRecord)?0:date('d-m-Y H:i:s',  strtotime($model->StartTime)), 'timeFormat' => 'HH:mm:ss',), // jquery plugin options
                        'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'form-control floating-label','readonly'=>true,'placeholder'=>'End Date','value'=>$endTime),
                    ));
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you looked at my answer ? i tested it works

Comment: No it is not working. `onSelect' => 'js:function( selectedDate ) {
                                            
                                                            $("#JobSchedule_EndTime").datetimepicker({ minDateTime : selectedDate});
                                                       }'`. i set like above. but doesn't set time.

Comment: is selectedDate instance of Date ? i think selectedDate is a string. Try with predefined date minDateTime : new Date('11 May 2015') if fails check extension

Comment: read more about Date type https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

There are two variables in source file minDateTime and maxDateTime, i think you need to reinitialize widget through javascript each time when you select first date.

https://github.com/magefad/EJuiDateTimePicker/blob/master/assets/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

Try

```
$('...').datetimepicker({
    minDateTime : new Date('11 May 2015')
});
```

There are two different versions (use version from github) :

1. http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ejuidatetimepicker/
2. https://github.com/magefad/EJuiDateTimePicker/

Comment: it doesn't help me. if i select 1st datetimepicker then  it only update date of 2nd datetimepicker date. it doesn't set time. i want to set minimum time in 2nd datetimepicker. I exactly want it to set time in slider. Any help please.